# Caluclate the values based on option selection

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor-pages

I am implementing razor pages for the first time. I want to implement a logic to caluclate a value based on the option selction.

cshtml

```
<form name="paymentform"  method="post">
    <fieldset>

<label for="package">package:</label>
        <select asp-for="package" asp-items="Model.packagelist">
            <option value="">Pick one</option>
        </select>

<label for="amt">price:</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

cshtml.cs

```
{
namespace testproject
    [BindProperties]
    public class testModel : testModel
    {
   public int package  { get; set; } = 3;
        public List<SelectListItem> packagelist { get; set; }

 public void OnGet()
        {
            packagelist = new List<SelectListItem> {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "5", Text = "t1" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "10", Text = "t2" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "12", Text = "t3" },
    };
}
}
```

i want to caluclate the value of price = sum of option value and variable x=4.
please guide me on implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding some simple js function on select change?

```
$('#package').change(function () {
        var x = 4;
        $('#amt').html("price:" + (parseInt($(this).val()) + 4));
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

On the server-side, you can use `POST` method and make your changes.  First add a new property to the model such as `selectedpackage`.

```
namespace testproject
    [BindProperties]
    public class testModel : testModel
    {
   public int package  { get; set; } = 3;
   public List<SelectListItem> packagelist { get; set; }
   public int selectedpackage { get; set; }
 public void OnGet()
        {
            packagelist = new List<SelectListItem> {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "5", Text = "t1" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "10", Text = "t2" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "12", Text = "t3" },
    };
}
```

On client side you will need to make the following changes

```
    <form name="paymentform"  method="post">
    <fieldset>

<label for="selectedpackage">package:</label>
        <select asp-for="selectedpackage" asp-items="Model.packagelist">
            <option value="">Pick one</option>
        </select>

<label for="amt">price:</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

On POST you can do this

```
public void OnPost()
    {
        var amount = selectedpackage + 4;
        //do whatever else you need to
    }
```